# Guardar el texto de una caja de texto en un string

Tags: string, qt, gridview, model

Estoy haciendo un programa en QT con el fin de crear un formulario y poder guardar la información en un document. He creado mi View para el formulario (donde introducirá el usuario el nombre), pero ahora no se como guardar lo que se escriba ahí en un String. ¿Podéis ayudarme? Gracias!!

Aclaración: mi objetivo es guardar el texto que se escriba en el QLineEdit en un al hacer presionar un pushButton en un string.

Aclaración2: si que me salta a la función `saveTheText` cuando presiono el botón pero no consigo guardar el mensaje ni hacer display del mismo.

Aquí el header de mi View:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFormLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QGroupBox>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QLineEdit>

class QGroupBox;
class QLabel;

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent=nullptr);
private slots:
    void saveTheText();
private:

    QGroupBox *myGroup;
    QPushButton *p_saveButton;
    QLineEdit *p_editName;
    QString *getName;

};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Aquí el .cpp de mi View:

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "ModelOne.h"

#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTreeView>
#include <iostream>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow (parent)
{
    std::cout<<"HOLA"<<std::endl;

    QWidget *p_theCentralWidget = new QWidget(this);

    QGridLayout *p_myGrid = new QGridLayout(p_theCentralWidget);

    QLabel *p_labelName = new QLabel("Name", this);
    p_myGrid->addWidget(p_labelName,0,0);

    p_editName = new QLineEdit(this); //Por poner ponemos "this", pero puede ser "p_theCentralWidget"
    p_myGrid->addWidget(p_editName, 0, 1);

    p_saveButton=new QPushButton("Save name",this);
    p_myGrid->addWidget(p_saveButton,0,2);
    connect(p_saveButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(saveTheText()));

    setCentralWidget(p_theCentralWidget);
}

void MainWindow::saveTheText()
{

    std::cout<<"HOLA222"<<std::endl;

    p_editName->displayText();

//    *getName=p_editName->text();
//    std::cout<<getName<<std::endl;

//    QString miString("ho");
//    miString=p_editName->text();


}
```

El main:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "MainWindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow window;
    window.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Y la ventana que obtengo al ejecutarlo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué pinta `ModelOne` en todo esto? Adicionalmente, sería de agradecer que comentases cómo (en qué momento, con qué acción, de qué manera) quieres recuperar el texto

Comment: Lo siento, no estaba clara la pregunta. He añadido una pequeña aclaración.

Comment: Vale, entonces te faltan muchas cosas: el botón, la captura del evento, la implementación del modelo...

Comment: Aquí te podemos ayudar a resolver una pregunta concreta... no a implementar todo lo que te he comentado (sobretodo la implementación del modelo... eso debería correr de tu cuenta)

Comment: He modificado la pregunta a algo más concreto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para recuperar el texto de un `QLineEdit` hay que utilizar el método `text()`:

```
void MainWindow::saveTheText()
{
  QString text = p_editName->text();
  qDebug << text;
}
```

Comment: ¿No debe ser `qDebug() << text;`?